# Doctrine ORM with $_GET Variables and security?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use some scripts where I have to sort for fields.

Nothing special really but I was wondering. I have this code:

```
$data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Data')->findBy(array("id" => $id), array($_GET["sort"] => $_GET["direction"]));
```

If I give a field in the `"sort"` that is non-existent there is only an error.
But could that get exploited for SQL Injection?

If so, what is the best way to avoid that?

Comment: Yet, don't use `$_GET`. Symfony provides an abstraction of queries via `Request->query`. Second, you should whitelist the fields that can be sorted on and check whether the input given is in the list. If not, fallback to the default one

Comment: Yeah but the abstraction doesn't clean anything on itself, it simply gives me a Class which I can use (what I do btw. but I use my own class). It has nothing to do with the Problem.

Comment: So what? Since good practices don't *immediately* solve the problem, you choose not to use them?

Comment: No - it was simply not necessary to make the code more complex to answer my question.
In fact, if I would have used another class that maybe filters malicious code from the GET Variable, i could have get the wrong answer because everyone assumes that my code would be safe because of the Abstraction Class I chose.
If i want to build a Table, I don't need to know how i could construct a house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $_GET["sort"] will be used to pass in a field to sort on everyone could fill in whatever they want to sort on... I don't think much harm can be done because doctrine will filter out bad things but still I don't recommend to do this. Try cleaning up at least the $_GET["sort"] and $_GET["direction"] fields.

Comment: So you recommand treating bad user inputs by awaiting doctrine's Exceptions? If a wrong `sort` field is given, Doctrine will generate an exception: `ORDER BY nonexistantfield ASC` will trigger an error.

Comment: I don't know what his purposes are with this because he didn't mention it. But since het explicitly inserts a variable as field name to sort on I guess it is required for him so he should catch the nonexistantfield exception if there is one...

Comment: Plain and simple answer - Thank you very much :)
You are right, I want to catch the exception - just wanted to know if it would be a possible security risk if I don't white-list everything (which would be a bit problematic in my application).

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment into an answer.

## Usage of the Request abstraction

Yet, your code has an issue. You're using superglobal `$_GET`.
Symfony offers a strong abstraction of inputs via `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` object. Use it!

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Controller/FooController

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function fooAction(Request $request) // First way
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();   // Another way
    $request = $this->get('request'); // Another way
}
```

To get your *"sort"* parameter, just do

```
$request->query->get('sort');
```

## Whitelist all the things

Since the user input may should `sortby` , you should validate WHICH fields it can be sorted on.

```
$allowed = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
$sort    = $request->query->get('sort');

if (!in_array($input, $allowed)) {
    $sort = $allowed[0];
}

$by = $request->query->get('direction');

if (!in_array($by, array('asc', 'desc')) {
    $by = 'asc';
}

$emanager->findBy(array('id' => $request->query->get('id'), $sort => $by));
```

We can directly input the user data into ID, doctrine will filter on with parameterized queries. However, the `sort` column is now safe, since, even if the column doesn't exist,  it will fallback to another one which you know, exists *(since you whitelisted it)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your `$_GET` before using them in your request.

For example, if `$_GET["sort"]` is only numeric and between 0 and 50, check if it’s really a number between 0 and 50 before using in this request.

Just don’t use `$_GET` without protection in your request – it’s dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be exploted for sql injection. So I prefer whenever you are passing any user input the sql then it should be escaped before use in SQL.

IN your query Doctrine is handle all this things so you dont worry about sql injection.

Comment: For a field, not escaped, **filtered**!

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, you can do it, but why ary you don't use `Request` object? And for more security you can use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php) or better [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) PHP function for replacing any bad symbols or use [getAlnum()](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_getAlnum) method of parameterBug. Also I recommended use `try catch()` for catch and handle any exceptions. There is example:

```
try {
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Data')->findBy(
        array("id" => $id),
        array($this->get('request')->query->getAlnum("sort") => $this->get('request')->query->get("direction"))
    );
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // do something if exception occured
}
```